# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object Django 1.10

Tags: django, python-3.x

Ok, so after some searching, non of the related question adress my specific problem as far as I can tell. I obviously don't understand if they do, so I apologize for any redundacy.

This is my traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "csvimport.py", line 79, in 
>      f.save()
>    File "/home/blake/django_/venv/lib/python3.5/site->packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 752, in save
>      "unsaved related object '%s'." % field.name
>   ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related >object 'aircraft'.

This is the script in question: http://pastebin.com/Jks0HgEr

These are my models: http://pastebin.com/uGUqckqS

I can't tell why the function assignAircraft() isn't saving the Aircraft.aircraft_type object when its being called on line 56

Strangely though, the first instance of row[1] is being saved to the Aircraft model.

Also, any refinements / pep8 suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point the returning object of your function `assignAircraft`

```
def assignAircraft(row_id):
    if aircraft_queryset.filter(aircraft_type = row_id).exists():
        pass
    else:
        a = Aircraft(
            aircraft_type = row_id,
        )
        a.save()
    return Aircraft(aircraft_type = row_id)
```

this function does not return the saved instance, but a temporary instance `Aircraft(aircraft_type = row_id)`.

you should return the saved instance `a`, or if there is no existing items, something must be returned.

```
def assignAircraft(row_id):
    if aircraft_queryset.filter(aircraft_type=row_id).exists():
        # DO SOMETHING AND RETURN SOMETHING
    else:
        a = Aircraft(aircraft_type=row_id)
        a.save()
        return a
```

IMO, [`get_or_create` manager function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Ugh, such a painful mistake! I was staring waay too long! I'll look into get_or_create. Thanks!

Comment: I just had a chance to do this and it seems so simple but I got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "csvimport.py", line 56, in <module>
    aircraft = assignAircraft(row[1]),
  File "csvimport.py", line 31, in assignAircraft
    return a
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Comment: could you show the edited code? the error implies there's no saved instance which is necessary. what did your code do and return in `DO SOMETHING` part?

Comment: what is your goal for this code for line 59 `aircraft = Aircraft(aircraft_type = assignAircraft(row[1])),` ? I mean, `assignAircraft` produces `None` if there is some aircraft, else creates new aircraft instance. And then do you want to make another aircraft instance with `aircraft_type` is the previous save instance (or even `None`)? is the field `aircraft_type` is a `foreignKey` to itself?